# python27 errno 0 and 2 in a simple for-loop printing

Tags: python

I just used python27 to print the variable in a simple for loop.
It can print out a part of the results but it stopped suddenly and appeared the errno 0 and 2 which are described as an IOerror while the process of output.
I am super confused with this error

Here is my simple code:

```
def checkPrint():
    for i in range(0,1000):
        print i

checkPrint()
```

And here is the output and error:

> 0 . . . 287 288 289 290
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File ".\checkPrint.py", line 5, in 
>       checkPrint()
>   File ".\checkPrint.py", line 3, in checkPrint
>       print i
>
> IOError: [Errno 0] Error

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide more details? This code is running without an issue, I think something related to your file system is broken while running the code.

Comment: @M.OğuzÖzcan I just ran it in vscode. I have tried ran it in powershell and IDLE. Powershell sometimes can run it completely without error but sometimes cant. And IDLE has no problem at this moment. I tried reinstall the python and vscode but cant fix this problem

Comment: Could you try to run it from cmd?

Comment: @M.OğuzÖzcan I have tried ran it in powershell and IDLE. Powershell sometimes can run it completely without error but sometimes cant. And IDLE has no problem at this moment. I tried reinstall the python and vscode but cant fix this problem

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the asker's scenario, but I was receiving this error anytime I ran the reproduction script in [Hyper 1.4.8](https://hyper.is) (with powershell.exe as my shell).

Using Command Prompt or PowerShell outside of Hyper avoided the error.

Comment: Can also happen when using VS Code running simple python with the powershell as default integrated terminal. Solution for me was to run it with an external terminal instead.

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40966 or https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36630.

This error happens when using vscode's integrated terminal in my case. Running in Command Prompt or PowerShell have no error.

According to Tyriar from the second issue, this is a problem with Windows, not vscode, to be fiexed.

Comment: This is a Windows bug that was fixed with Windows 10 Version 1803. (see https://bugs.python.org/issue32245 and https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36630#issuecomment-385759625 )

It affects Python 3.6+ when using code paths that call WriteFile, i.e. os.write and legacy standard I/O mode, and also always affects Python 2.7 and Python 3.5.