# python print with IOError: [Errno 0] Error

Tags: python-2.7, printing, ioerror

```
ll=[]
for ii in range(26):
    ll.append(chr(97+ii))

for ii in range(10000):
    print ll
```

When I print like this, it will report some error, Why?!

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/czh/python/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print ll
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476304/python27-errno-0-and-2-in-a-simple-for-loop-printing?rq=1)?

Comment: It seems to be a common windows 10 bug, I have it also occasionally on printing in the console. As a workaround you could `try except` around the print statement until it's fixed...

Comment: thanks for your reply, maybe that's the problem and the only solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Windows bug that was fixed with Windows 10 Version 1803.  (see https://bugs.python.org/issue32245 and https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36630#issuecomment-385759625 )

It affects Python 3.6+ when using code paths that call WriteFile, i.e. `os.write` and legacy standard I/O mode, and also always affects Python 2.7 and Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

**Another answer:**

I also met same problem in Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

I ran into this issue When I want to process some text which contains Chinese Character.

the core code is:

```py
content = fp.read().strip().strip("\n").split("\n")  # fp is an opened file obj
line = "".join([content[x] for x in [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16]])
print(line)
```

**the right way is: *using unicode instead of str(utf-8) before iter it***

```py
content = fp.read().strip().strip("\n").decode("utf-8").split("\n") # fp is an opened file obj
line = "".join([content[x] for x in [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16]])
print(line)
```